# Path not working; using File.separator

Tags: java, path, separator

I'm using:

- jdk 1.8.0.71
- IntelliJ 2016.3.2
- Win7

I was curious why this path is not working:

```
public static final String ZPL_TEMPLATE =
                    File.separator
                    + "templates"
                    + File.separator
                    + "Template.txt";
```

yet this one works fine:

```
public static final String TEMPLATE = "/templates/Template.txt";
```

Here is where is used (this is in another package):

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(TEMPLATE);
```

**EDIT:** the exception:

```
...
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    ...
```

Comment: Apologies for the very dumb question, but are you sure "/templates/ZPLTemplate.txt" exists? The example you gave as working is "/templates/Template.txt" without the ZPL. Just checking.

Comment: Also, could you give us details of the error you are getting?

Comment: try using `FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator();`

Comment: Sorry @phss, it's "Template"

Comment: Could you check (print out) what ZPL_TEMPLATE is? I suspect File.separator, on Windows, is '\\' rather than '/'. That might be the issue.

Comment: @Jobin `FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator();` is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When accessing a internal resource, like you did with `getResouceAsStream`, the file separator must be `/`.

I believe that you are in a Windows machine, so the file separator is `\`.

For more information, see [How to use file separator when loading resources](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2006/12/how_to_use_file_separator_when/).

Comment: The link you provided is not working (at least not for me)

Comment: Fixed. It was an extra space at the end... Thanks, @4673_j

Comment: Right.. I was hoping for some sort of system separator; but I guess simplicity is better, fairly clear in the link provided. Forward slash it is then.

Comment: The concept is that when you change of Operation System (OS), like Windows or Linux, the file separator change, so it is necessary to create a constant for it. But in the case of the separator for the resources, it is the same for every OS, so there is no need for it.

Answer (score 2):

Becaseuse file separator on Win 7 is '\' and as it states in doc for **getResourceAsStream**

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>   Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>   modified_package_name/name
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Answer (score 1):

`getResourceAsStream` expect a resource name as a parameter, not a file path.

**Resources names** in java are separated by forward slashes `/`, no matter the file system (Resources names/path represents a path on the classpath, not on the filesystem).

Hence, you can't use the file system seperator to build the resource name. On windows, it will be a backslash `\`